# Pygame doesn't CLOSE

Tags: python, pygame

Can someone PLEASE tell me what I'm doing wrong. I can't get my stupid program to close. It has a spinning circle(windows) and it doesn't close upon quit or keypress on the space bar.

```
 def visualize(self):
    pygame.init()
    main_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                break
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    break
                pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()
```

I'm not sure if the inside of my program matters much, but if it does, I'll add it. I would REALLY appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `break` will just exit the innermost loop, which is the `for` loop. You should have a condition variable for your `while` loop

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            break
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                break
            pygame.display.flip()
```